# Reuse data from api call with Alamofire in other views in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

let's say that when I load the `MainViewController` I make an api call and use that data on the same controller.
The data from that api call I need to also use in other view (`SidebarTableViewController`).

So where can I store the response from API so I can access later in other views?

Is singleton on models a good approach?

```
class Station: NSObject {
.................

public var stations     = [Station]()
static let instance     : Station = Station()

func fetchStations(successCB : @escaping () -> Void)
    {
      ..........
      for (_, station) in response["stations"] {
         ............
         self.stations.append(StationItem)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a problem with using a database or encoding the class and storing it to the `UserDefaults`

Comment: Why can't you just pass the object in `performSegue`?

Comment: I could do that, but I read that is best practice to send data via segue.